# curl post dont works fine

Tags: php, post, curl

I've a little problem,

here's my curl function:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
    $log = array(
    'login'     => $_SESSION['user'],
    'password'  => $_SESSION['password'],
    'remind'    => 'on'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($log));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $log);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.pt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.pt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;}
```

but the result of $data is the raw $url ( the log page ), why I can't log with the information I pass in $log ?

the POST form target is correctly typed. I don't understand

For information the $url is the intranet of my school, and I need the $data (loggued ofc) to preg some infos.

the form of $url is basic:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Connexion</legend>

        <div class="login input">
            <label for="auth-input-login">Login</label>
            <input type="text" id="auth-input-login" name="login" placeholder="Login" />
        </div>
        <div class="password input">
            <label for="auth-input-password">Mot de passe</label>
            <input id="auth-input-password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" type="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="remind input">
            <input id="auth-input-remind" name="remind" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="auth-input-remind">Se souvenir de moi</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
    </div>
</form>
```

the post result:
http://s22.postimg.org/ta6kivcep/Screen_Shot_2014_05_21_at_15_38_21.png

Comment: do you know how post request is being handled on that page? maybe they add random session to POST?

Comment: I edited my post, how can they add random session ? I don't understand

Comment: sometimes pages add hidden values (usually random numbers/letters) and also send it with POST request. Anyway, it is hard to guess how PHP part of the code looks like without seing content. Do you have access to that PHP file?

Comment: ok I get it, but here is not the problem, I guess the post is not submited because I have the raw page.

Comment: should not $log(post parameters) be converted to string before sending it with curl? at least that is what i used so far. for example like [this page](http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/)

Comment: action is same page where the form is (notice action=""), so that page probably have some way to check if post parameters are there process them, otherwise show form for login.

Comment: even with foreach($params as $k => $v) 
   { 
      $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
   }
   rtrim($postData, '&'); It didnt works

Comment: again, you need to know how PHP code looks like. Any redirection, session etc can result in a problem. Ask the person who did that page to show you how they process form elements.

Comment: I works in local, maybe that's why ?
Another student of my school done a script like mine, and the only difference betwen his code and mine is his code is OO and mine not.

Comment: I added an img of the post result, and ofc there is only login & password

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST` should be set to `true` rather than a number. Not sure that will fix your issue though. Try hard coding your username and password and see if that works as it could be a problem with your `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: curlopt_post is true because count($log) return 1.
I already tried to hardcode and didnt works too

Comment: @oxmolol The message you posted in your OP has nothing to do with what you receive from the curl call. That's what you (the browser) receive from the server.

Comment: I think I explain very bad the situation.
I need to get the source of my intranet
I did it well, but I receive the unlog page
So it works fine, I receive my page, but i need to have this page LOGGUED, unfortunately curl_setopt POST don't works